# Selenium IE Webdriver has an connection issue at start up

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, browser-automation

I need to use selenium webdriver to test with IE. I followed exactly the same instructions from the official google code project document. and I'm able to launch the IE webdriver with the code but get the following error

```
File "c:\python27\scripts\behave-script.py", line 9, in <module>
  load_entry_point('behave==1.2.3', 'console_scripts', 'behave')()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\behave\__main__.py", line 111, in main
  failed = runner.run()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 474, in run
  return self.run_with_paths()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 504, in run_with_paths
  failed = feature.run(self)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 410, in run
  failed = scenario.run(runner)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 676, in run
  runner.run_hook('before_scenario', runner.context, self)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 465, in run_hook
  self.hooks[name](context, *args)
File "c:\work\niqs\environment.py", line 24, in before_scenario
  context.driver = getattr(webdriver, WEB_DRIVER)()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 54, in __init__
  desired_capabilities=capabilities)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 71, in __init__
  self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 113, in start_session
  'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 162, in execute
  response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 350, in execute
  return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 391, in _request
  return self._request(resp.getheader('location'), method='GET')
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 382, in _request
  resp = self._conn.getresponse()
File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
  response.begin()
File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin
  version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
  line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
File "c:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 476, in readline
  data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

1. I had no proxy or firewall issues with the connection
2. the same code can be executed with Firefox
3. my testing enviroment is win7(64bit) IE 9/10/11 and IEDriverServer_x64_2.38.0.zip

does anyone has similar situation before? thanks

Comment: IE9 doesn't support sockets - [link](http://caniuse.com/websockets). May be this is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, my coworker had the same issue with IE10.

Comment: One another thing, is security settings of IE9. Protected mode should be in the same state for each zone, Does it now?

Comment: yes, the protected mode setting is another error. also selenium checks the zoom setting if it's not 100%, then another error with the corresponding message is showed.

Comment: Sry, no more ideas from me.

Comment: trying on several combinations, I found it doesn't work on the latest selenium 2.38.0, I changed to selenium 2.36.0 and it's correpsonding IEDriverServer binding, it works. but the input is very slow

Comment: Any difference in using the 32bit version? I would also mention you won't have much luck with IE11 at the moment anyway.

Comment: 32bit is the same, as mentioned, the latest selenium 2.38.0 has a defect, I had no issue with 2.36.0

Comment: I tried the following:
Selenium 2.38 + Ie Driver 2.38 (Same Issue), 
Selenium 2.38 + Ie Driver 2.36 (Same Issue), 
Selenium 2.36 + Ie Driver 2.38 (Another Issue), 
Selenium 2.36 + Ie Driver 2.36 (Another Issue), 

which configuration works to you?

Comment: 2.36.0 + 2.36.0 64bit